# dell inspiron 7559 hangs on live boot HELP!

Tags: boot, nvidia, dell

i need some help trying to install ubuntu in my system. Every time I try to book into the live cd or USB it hangs.

I have 2 graphics card I believe. One is Intel and the other is Nvidia. 
Could that maybe the problem?

please help 
this picture will show where ubuntu hangs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDyIP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop as you do, I fixed the boot problem by adding nouveau.modeset=0 to the grub linux line. Detailed instructions are in the following thread! After booting, make sure that you install Nvidia drivers.

[NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:305]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305/880933#880933)