# Ubuntu MATE does not shutdown or restart

Tags: shutdown

When i want to shutdown my computer or restart it , it just hangs on the process and prints this text on the screen :

```
[12.213313] Watchdog: Bug: Soft -Lockup On #cpu 0
```

Please tell me whats the problem.
Thanks

Comment: You might have a problem with Caps Lock. Please write lower case.

Comment: Please add some details about your system. Install the `inxi` package and add output of `inxi -v3` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert, to fully use `-v3`, *sudo* seems to be required. Also, adding `-z` would help to hide some user-sensitive information such as MAC addresses.

Comment: @samyarsadatakhavi, please add output of `sudo inxi -v3 -z` to the question. Thanks, *DK Bose*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! \[plymouthd:305\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305)