# How to change threshold for 'watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#xx stuck for 23s!'?

Tags: kernel, watchdog

Sometimes I can see this log if the system is in heavy loading.

I would like to extend this threshold ( 23 seconds? ) persistently.

Any way to setup it in grub or command line?

Comment: You really don't want to do that. This message is indicative of other problems in your system. Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` then check the manufacturer's web site for an update. Check your RAM vs swap with `free -h`. Check for AMD processor recalls that only effect Linux. Check for processes taking too much CPU time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! \[plymouthd:305\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305)