# My ubuntu 22.04 is stuck on boot screen only when restarting

Tags: boot, screen, reboot, watchdog

It works fine when I power on it but if I restart it it would be stuck. when I looked at the logs it said `watchdog:bug: soft lockup.`

[image: This is the logs while restarting]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! \[plymouthd:305\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305)